# What is the best practice to store User-Id from SSO in our sub systems to handle user changes and auditing log?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I am implementing a project with some dedicated applications (Sub Systems) which use **single-sign-on** (SSO) with **IdentityServer4** which is fabulous and so handy.

I'm just wondering what is the best practice to store UserId in dedicated applications that use this SSO to authenticate?

I mean for user auditing logs or logs of user changes I must just store the UserId(plus username and some other information) from SSO application in other applications ? or there are some other best practices way?

Answer (score 1):

What you should store is the subject (sub) claim as provided by IdentityServer, that is the true unique id for a given user. Email/username/name can always change.  Of course its ok to store both sub and username.

Comment: So you confirm that during authentication,  get UserUniqueId from IdentityServer in each subsystem and store as a userId in it?

Comment: You get the userID from the ID-token itself, so no need to query IdentityServer for user info unless you need more information than is found inside the ID-token.

Comment: Thank dude, this is my idea that I thought about that. Frankly, I have thought that maybe there are another bestpractise and tricky way. But Thanks.

Comment: Once you get the tokens there's no need to contact IdentityServer unless you want more details about the user or if you want to renew the access token or check if the token is still valid.